# python dictionary list creation with for loop

Tags: python, json, list, for-loop

I tried to create a python dictionary list with the following code`enter code here`

```
d={}
dlist=[]
key=["aa","bb","cc"]
file=["fileA","fileB","fileC"]

for i in range(len(key)):
  d['key']=key[i]
  d['file']=file[i]
  dlist.append(d)
  print(d)
print(dlist)
```

dlist shows

```
[{'key': 'cc', 'file': 'fileC'}, {'key': 'cc', 'file': 'fileC'}, {'key': 'cc', 'file': 'fileC'}]
```

please explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never make a new copy of the `d` dictionary so you're just overwriting the same one and the list is just containing 3 references to the same dictionary. simply move the declaration of `d` inside the for loop.

```
for i in range(len(key)):
  d = {}
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a list comprehension

```
>>> dlist = [{'key':k, 'file':f} for k,f in zip(key, file)]
>>> dlist
[{'key': 'aa', 'file': 'fileA'}, {'key': 'bb', 'file': 'fileB'}, {'key': 'cc', 'file': 'fileC'}]
```

The problem with your current code is you are re-using your dict `d` instead of making a new object within your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are appending the dict `d` reference in the list, so for all for loop iteration same dict refernece is added ie `id` of all element in the `dlist` is same. because of this last iteration value is added there.

below code can help you solve issue where you create a new dictionary in each for loop and then append it to list

```
dlist=[]
key=["aa","bb","cc"]
file=["fileA","fileB","fileC"]

for i in range(len(key)):
  d = {}
  d['key']=key[i]
  d['file']=file[i]
  dlist.append(d)
  print(d)
print(dlist)
```